# Protected route is inaccessible due to props being passed

Tags: reactjs

I have a simple application and am attempting to make an admin section of it inaccessible to users which are not authenticated. The issue I am having is that the below `userAuth` is always set to false and so the protected route is inaccessible, even for users which are logged in with the appropriate localStorage authentication in place. My thoughts are that the userAuth is being set to false as its initial state and the useEffect is not overwriting this when a request is made to the protected route URL.

Below is the routing I have so far:

```
import { lazy, Suspense, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route
} from "react-router-dom";
import * as ROUTES from './constants/routes';
import ProtectedRoute from './helpers/ProtectedRoute';

const Admin = lazy(() => import('./screens/Admin'));
const Home = lazy(() => import('./screens/Home'));
const Login = lazy(() => import('./screens/Login'));
const NotFound = lazy(() => import('./screens/NotFound'));
const Signup = lazy(() => import('./screens/Signup'));

const App = () => {

  const [userAuth, setUserAuth] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => { 
    const checkUser = () => {
      const user = localStorage.getItem("userAuth");
      if (user) {
        setUserAuth(true);
      } else {
        setUserAuth(false);
      }
    }
    checkUser();
  }, []);

  return (
    <Router>
      <Suspense fallback={<p>Loading ...</p>}>
        <Switch>
          <Route path={ROUTES.HOME} component={Home} exact={true} />
          <Route userAuth={userAuth} path={ROUTES.LOGIN} component={Login} />
          <Route userAuth={userAuth} path={ROUTES.SIGNUP} component={Signup} />
          <ProtectedRoute userAuth={userAuth} path={ROUTES.ADMIN} exact>
            <Admin />
          </ProtectedRoute>
          <Route component={NotFound} />
        </Switch>
      </Suspense>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I have a useEffect which is pulling in whether the user has been authenticated. This is set when the user submits a successful POST request for the Login page:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Link, useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import Header from '../components/Header';
import * as ROUTES from '../constants/routes';

const Login = ({setUserAuth}) => {

    const history = useHistory();

    const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
    const [loginErr, setLoginErr] = useState(false);
    
    const isUsernameValid = username.length > 0;
    const isPasswordValid = (password !== '' && password.length > 5);
    const isLoginValid = isUsernameValid && isPasswordValid;

    useEffect(() => {
        document.title = 'Login';
    }, []);

    const logIn = async (e, username, password) => {

        e.preventDefault();

        const data = {username, password}
        const formData = JSON.stringify(data);

        try {
          const req = await fetch(
            "http://localhost:3000/api/login",
            {
              method: "POST",
              body: formData,
              headers: {
                Accept: "application/json",
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
              },
            }
          );
          const myJson = await req.json();
          if (req.status !== 200) {
            setLoginErr(true);
            return;
          }
          localStorage.setItem("token", myJson.token);
          localStorage.setItem("userAuth", true);
          setUserAuth(true);
        } catch (err) {
          setLoginErr(true);
        }
    }

    return (
        <div className="bg-gray-100">
            <div className="container h-screen mx-auto flex flex-col flex-wrap">
                <div className="container border rounded m-auto w-1/4 flex flex-wrap justify-center bg-white shadow-new">
                    <h1 className="text-3xl m-4">Blog.</h1>
                    <form className="flex flex-wrap justify-center" onSubmit={(e) => logIn(e, username, password)}>
                        <input 
                            className="border rounded w-9/12 p-1 mb-2 pl-2 bg-gray-100 outline-none" 
                            name="username"
                            placeholder="Username"
                            value={username}
                            onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)}
                        />
                        <input 
                            className="border rounded w-9/12 p-1 mb-4 pl-2 bg-gray-100 outline-none" 
                            name="password"
                            placeholder="Password"
                            type="password"
                            value={password}
                            onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
                        />
                        <button 
                            className={`border rounded w-9/12 p-1 mb-4 bg-blue-400 text-white font-medium ${isLoginValid ? "cursor-pointer" : "bg-opacity-50 cursor-default"}`}
                            type="submit"
                        >Log In</button>
                        <div className="mb-4">
                            <p>Don't have an account? <Link to={ROUTES.SIGNUP} className="font-medium text-blue-500 cursor-pointer">Sign up</Link></p>
                        </div>
                        {loginErr && <p className="text-xs text-red-600">Error with login information</p>}
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>    
        </div>
    )

}

export default Login;
```

Here is the protected route:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import * as ROUTES from '../constants/routes';

const ProtectedRoute = ({ userAuth, children, ...rest }) => {

    return (
        <Route
            {...rest}
            render={({ location }) => {
                if (userAuth && userAuth !== null) {
                    console.log(userAuth)
                    console.log("FIRST")
                    // Using cloneElement to add / modify the props of its children.
                    return React.cloneElement(children, { userAuth });
                }
                
                if (!userAuth || userAuth === null) {
                    console.log(userAuth)
                    console.log("SECOND")
                    return (
                        <Redirect
                            to={{
                                pathname: ROUTES.LOGIN,
                                state: { from: location }
                            }}
                        />
                    );
                }

                return null;
            }}
        />
    )
}

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

Any advice would be highly appreciated.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

The issue seems to be that the `Login` component doesn't receive `setUserAuth` as a prop because it's rendered by a standard `Route` component on the `component` prop, meaning it only is passed route props.

## Solution

Render `Login` on the `render` prop and pass in the additional props. This will allow the login page to update the `userAuth` state in the parent component for the private routes.

```
<Route
  path={ROUTES.LOGIN}
  render={routeProps => (
    <Login
      {...routeProps}
      setUserAuth={setUserAuth}
    />
  )}
/>
```

Remove the mounting `useEffect` hook and use a state initializer function to set the initial `userAuth` state from localStorage so it's available on the initial render.

```
const [userAuth, setUserAuth] = useState(() => {
  const user = localStorage.getItem("userAuth");
  return !!user;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Drew. It actually only required the second part of your solution regarding the removal of the mounting ```useEffect``` hook. I can see that the original ```Login``` route has access to ```setUserAuth```.

Comment: @Tjm92 Oh interesting, I don't see from your snippet where `Login` is passed a `setUserAuth` prop, but if it's working for you. 

Answer (score 0):

Your `useEffect` hook checks whether the user is logged in only at component mount. You should move `const user = localStorage.getItem("userAuth")` outside the hook, and then add `user` in the dependency array of the hook so that the code will run on every change of the dependency (which is what will happen once the user successfully logs in)

```
 const user = localStorage.getItem("userAuth");

 useEffect(() => { 
    const checkUser = () => {
      if (user) {
        setUserAuth(true);
      } else {
        setUserAuth(false);
      }
    }
    checkUser();
  }, [user]);
```